# Aucuns ou aucun

Tags: accord, pluriel

Si je ne m'abuse, on écrit « aucuns sous-titres » mais quelle version est correcte avec la forme suivante :

> Sous-titres : aucun
>
> Sous-titres : aucuns

Je penche pour « *aucuns* » là aussi car « *sous-titres* » est au pluriel mais la question fait débat autour de moi.

EDIT : Je précise que le contexte est l'interface d'un lecteur de vidéos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En théorie, la règle est que si possible (si il existe et que le sens est le même), on utilise le singulier. Il ne s'emploie donc au pluriel qu'avec des noms qui n'ont pas de singulier ou dont le sens du singulier est différent de celui du pluriel.

Si on veut vraiment mettre le mot au pluriel (comme on trouve dans la littérature comme mentionné dans le commentaire de None), on accorde *aucun*. Dans ton cas, on peut arguer que *sous-titres* au pluriel a un sens différent du singulier, et dans ce cas-là on écrirait donc "*aucuns sous-titres*". La forme "*Sous-titres : aucuns*" serait donc correcte.

Cependant, même si c'est techniquement correct, voir "*aucuns*" dans une interface peut être un peu bizarre pour certains utilisateurs (dont moi avant de changer d'avis), et c'est peut-être mieux d'éviter complètement le mot. Dans le cadre d'une interface, il est probablement préférable d'éviter les formulations qui font débat si possible.

J'ai regardé comment font les autres , il y a plusieurs alternatives :

> Youtube : *Sous-titres : Désactiver les sous-titres*

> Netflix : *Sous-titres : désactivé* (sic)

> Amazon Prime : *Sous-titres : Sous-titres désactivés*

> Disney+ : *Sous-titres : Off*

> VLC : *Piste de sous-titres : Désactiver*

Comment: Et alors que fais-tu de *Ils n'osent faire aucuns projets* (Voltaire) ; *Ils ne possédaient aucuns royaumes* (Charles Péguy) ; *Aucunes choses ne méritent de détourner notre route* (André Gide) etc. etc ? J'ai cherché ou tu avais trouvé ce que tu dis,  tu pourrais [citer ta source](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aucun/6369). Et il y a peut-être plus fiable que le premier retour de google !

Comment: @None Tu as raison, c'est plus complexe que ça, je suis en train de modifier ma réponse. Pour répondre directement à ton commentaire, selon moi ça relève de la licence poétique (donc parfaitement légitime mais plutôt littéraire), et je pense que ça a sa place dans un livre mais dans le cadre d'une interface utilisateur en général on préfère éviter et se cantonner au français le plus "académique" possible.

Comment: Merci. Effectivement, le mieux est sûrement de reformuler.

Answer (score 4):

Puisque le mot sous-titre existe au singulier, il vaut mieux écrire « aucun sous-titre ». Que l'on parle de sous-titres au pluriel ne change pas la donne; je me vois mal dire « ****Aucuns** des sous-titres **ne sont affichés*** », ce sera toujours pour moi « ***Aucun** des sous-titres **n'est affiché*** ».

Dans le cas d'une liste vide introduite par deux points, le singulier me semble donc préférable pour la même raison :

> Sous-titres : aucun

[voo.be](https://assistance.voo.be/fr/support/tv/voocorder/utilisation/activer-les-sous-titres-d-un-programme-sur-mon-voocorder.html) :
[image]

[Nordnet](https://assistance.nordnet.com/kb/Changer-la-langue-et-afficher-les-sous-titres-dun-programme_480.html) :

[image]

[Orange](https://assistance.orange.fr/tv-decodeur/tous-les-decodeurs/installer-et-utiliser/parametrer-la-tv-d-orange/langues-et-sous-titres/decodeur-tv-4-regler-les-sous-titres-des-programmes-multilingue_170542-718709) :

[image]

---

On peut aussi contourner le problème comme ceci :

> Sous-titres : sans

Comment: Merci. Même si ça existe au singulier, on parle généralement "des" sous-titres d'un film et non "du" sous-titre, non ?

Comment: @Rodolphe Bien sûr qu'il y a plusieurs sous-titres dans un film... quand le film a des sous-titres. Si le film n'est pas sous-titré, il n'a pas de sous-titres, comme dit dans la réponse le singulier est préférable, question de logique.

Comment: @Rodolphe On parle aussi des passagers, au pluriel, par exemple d'un train, mais s'il n'y en a pas on dira *Il n'y a **aucun passager** dans ce train*, pas *il n'y a **aucuns passagers** dans ce train*.

Comment: Encore une fois, je ne discute pas ce point. Je suis entièrement d'accord. Ma question porte spécifiquement sur la tournure avec les deux points.

Comment: Passagers: aucun